# Wrong HNQ icon for Japanese

Tags: bug, hot-questions, favicon

[Cross site duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397158/994125) (as answer to the dark theme thread).

I was quite surprised to see a meta.3dprinting.SE question in my HNQ feed and even more so when it turned out to be a Japanese question! The icon seems to be borked, however with HNQs "instability" I don't know if there is a way to check if that's a caching issue or something else.

What *did* work however was changing this:

[image: favicon-japanese CSS class screenshot]

to

```css
.favicon-japanese {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

[image: Japanese.SE question showing up with meta.3dprinting.SE icon]

Browser: Firefox 76.0.1 64-Bit
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: This was already reported on Meta.SO [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397158/994125).

Comment: Also, all dark mode feedback goes to the above link by Laf as it is SO only right now.

Comment: I didn't know this was a dark mode issue; I would leave this post up in case someone else encounters it and searches for it on meta.SE.

Comment: Probably related to the launch of two new sites: [drones.se] and [materials.se]. That always causes this bug...

Comment: @Glorfindel is correct, whenever new sites are added, the server side cache holding the icons and the relevant CSS must be refreshed, and it always require lots of kicks until it actually agree to refresh.